# Earth-Based Nuclear Fusion - Choice of Reaction

Tags: nuclear-physics

I have read that most research Tokamaks fuse deuterium with tritium to form helium. I had a few questions if someone could kindly answer:

1) I have read that scientists want to harvest helium-3 from the moon for fusion on Earth. Since this will be an expensive endeavour I assume it is a better reaction than deuterium and tritium. Why?
2) More of an opinion from you guys but which method do you think will end up being used in nuclear fusion reactors once we crack the process of fusion -  Tokamaks, laser initiated fusion?

Comment: don't forget about Stellerators...

Comment: Yeh I saw this but this is for D-D vs He-3 as appose to D-T vs He-3